# how to post plain text to ASP.NET Web API endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, content-type

I have an ASP.NET Web API endpoint with controller action defined as follows :

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] object text)
```

If my post request body contains plain text ( i.e. should not be interpreted as json, xml, or any other special format ), then I thought I could just include following header to my request :

```
Content-Type: text/plain
```

However, I receive error :

```
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Object' from content with media type 'text/plain'.
```

If I change my controller action method signature to :

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string text)
```

I get a slightly different error message :

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String' from content with media type 'text/plain'.

Comment: don't you want your "text" parameter to be of the type string then?

Comment: yes i thought of that idea too but it doesn't help much ( please see my revised question )

Comment: @BaltoStar I know your question is 8 month old but I faced the same problem. See my answer below.

Comment: Hi BaltoStar, could you mark @gzou's answer as the answer? That would help the community seeing it as the answer. Thks

Answer (score 74):

Actually it's a shame that web API doesn't have a `MediaTypeFormatter` for plain text. Here is the one I implemented. It can also be used to Post content.

```
public class TextMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public TextMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    public override Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
        try
        {
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            readStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            taskCompletionSource.SetResult(s);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            taskCompletionSource.SetException(e);
        }
        return taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public override Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, System.Net.TransportContext transportContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var buff = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.ToString());
        return writeStream.WriteAsync(buff, 0, buff.Length, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(string);
    }
}
```

You need to "register" this formatter in your HttpConfig by something like that:

```
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new TextMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Comment: Exactly what I need!  Great stuff!

Comment: Great! This is an awesome solution !

Comment: I wonder why not simplify ReadFromStreamAsync method to just: 
return await new StreamReader(readStream).ReadToEndAsync();

Comment: My MediaTypeFormatter does not have the Cancellation Token parameter on `WriteToStreamAsync`. Works when I removed that argument.

Answer (score 24):

Since Web API doesn't have out of box formatter for handling text/plain, some options:

1. Modify your action to have no parameters... reason is having parameters triggers request body de-serialization. Now you can read the request content explicitly by doing `await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the string
2. Write a custom MediaTypeFormatter to handle 'text/plain'... it's actually simple to write in this case and you could keep the parameters on the action.

Comment: Thanks for the response Kiran. Actually, my action signature has additional [FromUri] parameters, which I left out to keep my question simple. So I guess this means I can't avoid implicit de-serialization of request body ? In which case I need to write a custom MediaTypeFormatter to handle 'text/plain' ....

Comment: request deserialization would only happen for the parameters which are `normally` considered to be read from body...examples: Explicitly `[FromBody]` decorated parameters, implicitly read from body(ex: complex types)...so my above answer only is for the ones meant to be read from the body...so you should be able to use `FromUri` parameters as usual...but in any case creating a custom formatter is the best approach as it fits well with Web API design..

Comment: Is it not dangerous to provide this formatter? text/plain is a valid enctype of a HTML form with post method. Be sure to add antiforgery token to prevent cross site request forgery.

Answer (score 22):

In ASP.NET Core 2.0 you simply do the following :-

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body))
{
      string plainText= reader.ReadToEnd();

      // Do something else

      return Ok(plainText);
}
```

Comment: Simple and perfect!

Comment: Helped me out in 2020. It should not have been so difficult to find this answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Excellent. For clarity, one must remove the [frombody] parameter from the method signature for this to work.

Answer (score 17):

Purified version using of gwenzek's formatter employing async/await:

```
public class PlainTextFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    public PlainTextFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));
    }

    public override bool CanReadType(Type type) =>
        type == typeof(string);

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type) =>
        type == typeof(string);

    public override async Task<object> ReadFromStreamAsync(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamReader(readStream);
        return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
    }

    public override async Task WriteToStreamAsync(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content, TransportContext transportContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var streamReader = new StreamWriter(writeStream);
        await streamReader.WriteAsync((string) value);
    }
}
```

Please note I **intentionally do not dispose** StreamReader/StreamWriter, as this will dispose underlying streams and break Web Api flow. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn479100(v=vs.118)):

> "An implementation of this method should not close readStream upon completion. The stream will be closed independently when the HttpContent instance is disposed."

To make use of it, register while building `HttpConfiguration`:

```
protected HttpConfiguration CreateHttpConfiguration()
{
    HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();
    ...
    httpConfiguration.Formatters.Add(new PlainTextFormatter());
    ...
    return httpConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: What will disposing break specifically? I found that not disposing of them caused error when handling exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

In some situations it might be simpler to let the JsonMediaTypeFormatter let do the work:

```
var formatter = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Where(f=>f is System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter).FirstOrDefault();
if (!formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Any( mt => mt.MediaType == "text/plain" ))
    formatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add( new MediaTypeHeaderValue( "text/plain" ) );
```

Comment: If I do this and then set the body like this: `resp.Content = new StringContent(outputString, Encoding.UTF8, "text\plain");`, will it just output the string as-is (even if it is not JSON) with the text-plain content-type?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to this party with a grossly simplified solution.
I had success with this code in the controller method:

```
       public HttpResponseMessage FileHandler()
       {
        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.GetBufferedInputStream()))
        {
            string plainText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        } .....}
```

And on the client side, these are the Ajax options I used:

```js
var ajaxOptions = {
url: 'api/fileupload/' + "?" + $.param({ "key": metaKey2, "File-Operation": "Remove", "removalFilePath": $removalFilePath, "Audit-Model": model, "Parent-Id": $parentId, "Audit-Id": $auditId }),
type: 'POST', processData: false, contentType: false, data: "BOB"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a proper answer, but a quick 'n dirty workaround to unblock development...

It turns out that a quote-delimited string by itself is valid JSON.  So if you know for sure that the content will always be very simple, you can wrap it in double quotes and call it application/json.

```
// TODO: Temporary, fix for production
HttpContent content = new StringContent($"\"{command}\"", UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Comment: Hi, I'm facing this problem asp.net weba api (.net 5) quotation works with IIS, but not with linux server (litespeed) some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since **.NET 5+** the formatters have be separated in `TextInputFormatter` & `TextOutputFormatter`. Therefore the resulting class for supporting plain text as body content has slightly changed:

```
public class PlainTextFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public PlainTextFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain));

        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.ASCII);
    }

    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type) => type == typeof(string);

    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
        var plainText = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        
        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(plainText);
    }
}
```

Register in the `Startup.cs` or `Program.cs`:

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.InputFormatters.Add(new PlainTextFormatter()))
```

And make sure to send your request with `Content-Type: text/plain`.

Here is a short blog post I've written about that which goes into a bit more detail: [Supporting text/plain Body content in .NET WebAPIs](https://medium.com/@ichwillkein/supporting-text-plain-body-content-in-net-webapis-54bbfd09ae09)