# POSTing JSON Object HTTPClient. Received Value is NULL WEB API ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, http

I'm trying to post JSON data to web api, both projects run on my local machine.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(@"http://localhost:53818/");
    var result = client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
    string resultContent = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    Console.WriteLine(resultContent);
}
```

Received values in This post method is NULL

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

EDIT -----------
So I managed to figure out what the issue was. I've substituted this line of code

```
client.PostAsync("api/values", new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

with the following and it worked, if someone will post the explanation I will be grateful

```
var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/values", data).Result;
```

Comment: What does `data` look like from your first snippet (where you make the request)?

Comment: My data is a JSON file which is generated in another method and is passed to this one, data is generated correctly

Comment: So is data named in a way that your WebAPI action signature will pick up with automatic binding?

Comment: @Jasen can you please explain in more details what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is becouse WebApi isn't good at serializing primitive types from the body, when you are sending the 'Content-Type' Header as application/json the framework is trying to serialize the content with the set Json serializer and isn't able, that's why you are getting null in the variable.

You can either

1. Change the type of the parameter from string to JToken or
2. Include a Media Type Formatter that handles plain text (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914360/1422608)

Comment: I changed the type of the parameter to JToken but now StringContent is throwing an exception

Comment: @IliaAptsiauri what exception is it throwing?

Comment: it says that no override method exists, I've tried to use data.toString() basically it's the same as it was and  it didn't work

Comment: How to use `MediaTypeFormatter `? I've added to my application, can you let me know..how we can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Because you call **values** and your method expect **value**.  Change your call to value or change the method signature for values which in this case would make more sense