# Trying to PUT string with Postman in local C# web api, always null or fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I currently have this WEB API running locally:

```
// POST api/CsvParse
[HttpPut]
public void Put([FromBody]string value)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        throw new Exception("Input is null or empty.");
}
```

I currently have it running locally, and am sending a string to the put using POSTMAN. I have selected the body tab, and have the string pasted into the raw body tab:

[image]

It states that my text is unsupported, or when I add a break point the value is null or I get the error describing the format is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there is no media type formatter that can serialize a raw string into your model (your route parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute).

A quick and dirty workaround is to directly read the body of your request as a string:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Put(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var myCsv = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // do stuff with your string

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

As an alternative you could implement a custom media type formatter yourself, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29914360/3670737).

Answer (score 2):

Change the media type to x-www-form-urlencoded rather than multipart/form-data.

Also, WebAPI is particular about FromBody parameters.
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

For you, I think this is the relevant part:

> 3. [FromBody] parameters must be encoded as =value
>
> The final hurdle remaining is that Web API requires you to pass
>   [FromBody] parameters in a particular format. That’s the reason why
>   our value parameter was null in the previous example even after we
>   decorated the method’s parameter with [FromBody].
>
> Instead of the fairly standard key=value encoding that most client-
>   and server-side frameworks expect, Web API’s model binder expects to
>   find the [FromBody] values in the POST body without a key name at all.
>   In other words, instead of key=value, it’s looking for =value.
>
> This part is, by far, the most confusing part of sending primitive
>   types into a Web API POST method. Not too bad once you understand it,
>   but terribly unintuitive and not discoverable.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a content type of `text/plain`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar Q&A [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22742560/406333)

I found that solution #1 worked for me as I was trying to PUT JSON containing the Key/Value pair. So originally my JSON looked like this

```
{
    "subscriber": {
    "Id": "2",
    "subscriptions":[
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 1",
            "Id": "18",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 2",
            "Id": "19",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 3",
            "Id": "20",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        }
    ]
    }
}
```

But I modified it to become

```
{
    "Id": "2",
    "subscriptions":[
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 1",
            "Id": "18",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 2",
            "Id": "19",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        },
        {
            "Name": "Subscription 3",
            "Id": "20",
            "IsSubscribed": false
        }
    ]
}
```

And that worked. My PUT request from Postman was recognised in my C# web api using [FromBody]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my bit, there is one more solution to pass primitives into a POST or a PUT method. Just specify the model as `JObject`. ASP.Net core web api then binds incoming JSON object(containing primitives like string) into JObject model object.

Your code would look like this:

```
// POST api/CsvParse
[HttpPut]
public void Put([FromBody]JObject value)
{
    //access your string data
    string data = value[SPECIFY_KEY_HERE];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
        throw new Exception("Input is null or empty.");
}
```