# text/plain Media Type not being accepted for WebApi v2

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-9, mediatypeformatter

This problem started off with IE9, where for `POST` requests, the `contentType` has to be `text/plain`, and `application/json` will not work.

I've added the [moonscript](https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest) and proceeded to use `contentType: text/plain`. I've also added the custom media type to the api, as shown on numerous forms below:

- http://www.stormbase.net/2015/09/21/webapi-post-plaintext/
- [how to post plain text to ASP.NET Web API endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631970/how-to-post-plain-text-to-asp-net-web-api-endpoint)

And added the insertion of the `text/plain` media type to the `WebApiConfig`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

// allows 'text/plain' as a supported media type
config.Formatters.Add(new TextMediaTypeFormatter());
```

However, when posting in IE9 (using emulation), I am still receiving a `415 Unsupported Media Type`

`Key        Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: hope_forms.viivApiUrl + 'newsletter',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    success: function (data) {
           .....
    },
    error: function (responseText) {
           console.log(responseText)
           modal.showModal('Something went wrong, please try again.');
   }                    
});
```

Addition:

Here's the full blown `WebApiConfig` in the event that something is out of order:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

// Uncomment the following line of code to enable query support for actions with an IQueryable or IQueryable<T> return type.
// To avoid processing unexpected or malicious queries, use the validation settings on QueryableAttribute to validate incoming queries.
// For more information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=279712.
//config.EnableQuerySupport();

config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();


//config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented;

// allows 'text/plain' as a supported media type
config.Formatters.Add(new TextMediaTypeFormatter());
```

I also changed the `ajaxTransport xhr` wrapper to use this instead:
https://github.com/gfdev/javascript-jquery-transport-xdr

---

**Note:**

As of today, 09/21, I've switched all my `POST` requests to `GET`, but I still would like a work-around to get these types back to `POST`.

Comment: Try to change `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));` to `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));`

Comment: The `TextMediaTypeFormatter` class adds that (which is in the (2) links that I posted from other forms.

Comment: Just a guess - but after reading the both articles I cannot get the reason why to add text/html to the JsonFormatter. I mean the first line, not the adding of the TextMediaTypeFormatter.

Comment: @Rob Scott  please check your web api response in advance rest client or  postmen with your publish URL because of  when web api throw error then it's return html response [AdvanceRest ](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo)

Comment: add in ajax call   `dataType: 'json'` or contentType:'application/json' and check your response in  chrome advance rest tool  i hope it help you

Comment: @jayeshdhameliya - depending on whether or not `XDomainRequest` object is present or not (IE9), the `contentType` is switched from `json` to `text/plain`. Please note that in order to `POST` w/ IE9, the `xhr` wrapper is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've run into the strange XDomainRequest issue that cropped up in 2014 according to [this MSDN blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ieinternals/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds/)

> Note: As of 2014, XDomainRequest doesn’t appear to send any Content-Type header at all. It’s not clear to me when this changed.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487216/cors-with-jquery-and-xdomainrequest-in-ie8-9) a previous SO question on the topic as well which actually references that blog.

This is also backed up by the documentation for the jQuery extension you are using. In the Readme.md

> XDomainRequest have some limitations:
>
> - there is no Content-Type header in request

So if you check `HttpContext.Request.ContentType` I'm betting it's going to be null / empty in which case you should be able to assign the response type of "text/plain" and pray to the gods it works.

Basically IE < 10 support for XDomainRequest (and even XDomainRequest itself) is garbage. It has been basically ditched to my understanding and [IE 10 implemented CORS support for XHR requests](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ie/2012/02/09/cors-for-xhr-in-ie10/)