# Testing API Post passing a <Frombody()> class - Always NULL

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I am creating an api conroller class in VB. I have a very simple function in it:

```
Public Function Post(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String) As String
    Return value
End Function
```

When I send a POST request from **HTTP Tool** (FireFox extension), I can see it go in the function, but `value` is always empty.

I have this in my `WebApiConfig.vb`:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:="Names",
        routeTemplate:="{controller}/{id}",
        defaults:=New With {.id = RouteParameter.Optional}
```

And this in `Global.ASAX.vb` under `Application-Start()`:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="Post", routeTemplate:="post", defaults:=New With {.symbol = RouteParameter.Optional, .controller = "Names"})
```

I tried this from **Fiddler 4** as well, but I get:

> {"Message":"The request contains an entity body but no Content-Type
>   header. The inferred media type 'application/octet-stream' is not
>   supported for this resource.","ExceptionMessage":"No
>   MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type
>   'application/octet-stream'.","ExceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent
>   content, Type type, IEnumerable '1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Type type, IEnumerable '1 formatters, IFormatterLogger
>   formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

Or when I try to set the content-type in the header I get:

> No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'String'
>   from content with media type ...

Where <...> is whatever media type I set.

How do I make this simple POST work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the framework you are using for your API doesn't know how to parse the content of the body of your POST request based on the content type header that you are setting in your request.

Also, your [API controller may not know how to parse plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25631970/how-to-post-plain-text-to-asp-net-web-api-endpoint).

You can either manually add a supported content type, or read in the request content manually according to one of the answers in the above link. Or you can change your controller to [accept a form post like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593595/is-there-a-way-to-handle-form-post-data-in-a-web-api-controller).

Comment: This is probably a fairly decent answer to the question. However, I have gone a different route and can't really justify the time re-testing this with the answer provided. Hopefully someone else finds this useful.